# React Conditional Renderings with states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, recharts

I have two `select options`, and i have to display the two teams data in the charts when i select the two teams: **Home Team** and **Away Team**

This is the prototype done with [codepen](https://codepen.io/Mannaio/pen/eXXVre?editors=0010)

At the moment i can only display in the chart one Line Component with `dataKey` and not the 2 Lines components for the two teams when i select both in the dropdowns.

How can i say in React when i select the Team Home in the first `Select` display the `hometeam` Line Component with the `datakey` state value.

```
{this.state.hometeam && <Line type='monotone' key={'1'} dataKey={this.state.value} stroke='#132908' yAxisId={1} activeDot={{fill: '#132908', stroke: 'none', r: 6}}/>}
```

Same for the `awayteam` in the other select

```
{this.state.awayteam && <Line type='monotone' key={'1'} dataKey={this.state.value} stroke='#132908' yAxisId={1} activeDot={{fill: '#132908', stroke: 'none', r: 6}}/>}
```

In the [demo](https://codepen.io/Mannaio/pen/eXXVre?editors=0010) i have only displayed the generic Line Component not depending on the state

Comment: the problem is from your handler, create two separate state items for Home and Away. currently you are just setting value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graph is driven off of this single `this.state.value` which is overwritten when either dropdown is selected. I would split that up into two separate properties in the state.

```
state = {
  data: initialState
  hometeamValue: '',
  awayteamValue: ''
}

handleChangeHomeTeam = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    hometeamValue: e.target.value,
  });
};

handleChangeAwayTeam = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    awayteamValue: e.target.value,
  });
};

render(){
  return(
    // ...
    <select value={this.state.hometeamValue} onChange={this.handleChangeHomeTeam}>
      <option value="Betis">Betis</option>
      <option value="Real">Real</option>
    </select>
    <select value={this.state.awayteamValue} onChange={this.handleChangeAwayTeam}>
      <option value="Betis">Betis</option>
      <option value="Real">Real</option>
    </select>
    // ...
    <Line dataKey={this.state.hometeamValue} ... />}
    <Line dataKey={this.state.awayteamValue} .../>}
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand the point, but i have problems with the values with your solution, what about the selection values with your changes?

Comment: Same error with the states, if you can please show in the codepen demo i can accept your answer

Comment: This is the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scale' of undefined

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have updated the codepen https://codepen.io/Mannaio/pen/eXoMob?editors=0010 with your changes and i get the same error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scale' of undefined

Comment: I'm not sure what your error is. The exact snippet i posted works fine when I paste all contents in codepen.